# NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I am trying to use oozie to call spark jobs. And the spark job can be run successfully without oozie using spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --class xxx --master yarn-cluster --files xxx/hive-site.xml --jars xxx/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,xxx/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,xxx/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar xxx.jar
```

But when I try to use oozie to call the job, it will always failed with the following error. I have involved the 3 external jars and hive-site.xml in the workflow.xml

```
Launcher exception: org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext
    at xxx$.main(xxx.scala:20)
    at xxx.main(xxx.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.runSpark(SparkMain.java:104)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:95)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:38)
```

The 20th line of my scala code is:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

Does anyone have any idea about this error? I have been stuck for several days.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could try doing `import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._` and then create the context directly: `val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)`

Comment: @DanieldePaula In my scala code, the 20th line is     val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc) which should be same as your suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion is just to try importing the class separately. Just a quick try to help you debug the problem, because the error will probably change.

Comment: Did you check that the version of Spark in the Oozie ShareLib (in `hdfs:///user/oozie/share/lib/*/spark/` or sthg like that) is *exactly* the same that you are using with the command-line? With the same compile options?? For instance, the Spark binaries that you can download from the Apache web site are compiled *without* Hive support...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thank you for the reply. I can see the spark directory following the path you mentioned but not sure how to check the version of this spark. I can only see a bunch of jar files inside spark folder. Which jar file do you think need to have Hive support?  spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Or do you mean we must have the library which is used by spark job in the share folder? For example, if I need to use spark_mllib, do I also need to have this jar file in the oozie's shared folder? I found there are no spark-mllib, spark-hive or spark-sql in the oozie's shared folder.

Comment: I'm not an expert when it comes to tweaking Oozie installation... What I did once for a client was a kind of ugly workaround: take a Spark install that works, ZIP the whole thing, upload to HDFS, attach to an Oozie **shell** action as an `<archive>/some/path/blah.zip#myspark</archive>` (dezipped in the container's CWD under sub-dir `myspark`) then from the shell script run `./myspark/bin/spark-submit ...`

Comment: Caveat: that workaround might also require the Oozie Sharelib for "Hive" if it is not installed on all nodes. Plus some tweaking on `spark.driver.extra****` to account for the difference (env vars & system CLASSPATH) between your gatway node and regular YARN nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Just came back to answer my own question. This one ends up being solved by updating the shared lib of oozie. Basically, the jars in the shared lib are not complete for my job to run. So I first imported some additional jars such as spark-hive and spark-mllib. Also the jars provided in oozie shared lib were too old, which also needed to be updated to avoid some potential errors.